# PHP Application Page / Username Conflict Resolution

Tags: php, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am building a PHP application. For my application, user's profiles / pages are setup and displayed intially by visiting domain.com/username or domain.com/accountnumber.

My question is this - how do you do that, while retaining the ability to make informative application pages that have the url of domain.com/pagename? My main example of this is vimeo, which has vimeo.com/about, vimeo.com/developers, etc., while allowing you to set your username to vimeo.com/username. My concern is that I will launch my application and not have the ability to create the link I want to in the future because it is taken as a username.

What would be your advice, or what has been your experience? Is there a common list to reserve that is recommended? I am not sure what to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If there is a better place to ask this question in in the StackOverflow network (like stackapps), please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You are in the right place :) If you are new to SO or StackExchange be sure to check out the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve what you asking - read up on routes and routing to gain a better understanding.

Many frameworks offer a way in achieving what you are asking - Zend Framework being one.

Alterantivly, if you are building it from scratch you could implement a different structure i.e.

```
domain.com/u/joebloggs  
domain.com/user/joebloggs  
domain.com/a/123456  
domain.com/account/123456
```

This effectivly ensures your urls cannot be affected by someone username. You'll need to look into [Mod Rewrite](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) if using creating your own routes.

Comment: lethalmango, I have considered this route (domain.com/u/username), and it is highest up on my list at this point. The strength of my application is being able to setup a custom domain for your account page (think Tumblr), so I should probably give a little on this part. My target is people that want to use a custom domain, not one's that are content with the app.com/username. **So thanks for your answer!**

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks available already that offer this ability, try [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/).

You'll need to read up on Routes with ZF to implemented what it is you require.

Comment: Although I am building from scratch (too much to go the Framework route at this point) - **Thanks for the answer.**

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you don't design your urls like that. I know vimeo does it, but they probably have run in to this headache.

A better solution is to namespace your resources. Look closely at stackoverflow's urls for better examples of good url design.

If you are absolutely stuck with this url design, consider organizing your "content tokens" (the bit of the url that identifies the thing you want) into groups, and giving them an order of priority. E.g.:

1. if token matches a static page, show static page
2. else search for and show user page by account name
3. else search for and show user page by account number

When users sign up, don't allow them to use names that are static pages. (You may want to reserve a set of static page names in advance.)

If you make a new static page later and a user name conflicts, you can forcibly change his user name and send him an "I'm sorry" email. This will hopefully be a rare enough occurrence that you don't need to solve it with code.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `curl` or similar to request `domain.com/requestedname` at the registration, returning an error to the user if the URL doesn't return a 404.  As for *future* conflicts, there is simply no way to do that.  You either have to make a list at the beginning of all potential future reserved words and disallow those usernames (impractical), cross your fingers and hope a conflict doesn't occur (also impractical), request a username change from the user when a future conflict occurs (unprofessional?) or use a different namespace for usernames and system pages.